# Jsf Haning Request

Tags: ajax, jsf, request

is there any standard Tag, or good taglib which enables "hanging request" in jsf without acutally coding it by myselfe?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean server push, I am aware of [icepush](http://www.icesoft.org/projects/ICEpush/overview.jsf) and push support in [primefaces](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/index.jsf). Both should get you what you need although there could be some minor problems with integration with  ThreadLocal based frameworks.

Comment: is the client-side javascript implemented as hanging-request or does it poll the server all the time?

Comment: The time thread is waiting for response is configurable, I've been using times of 20-30 seconds. After receiving response javascript immediately issues another request to wait for possible updates from the server.

Comment: can you show me an example? when i use "<a4j:push reRender="msg" eventProducer="#{pushBean.addListener}" timeout="20000"/>" it polls all the time

Comment: What do you mean all the time? Also please post it as another question, tagged with richfaces.

Comment: it sends a request every second

Comment: If you broadcast every second on the server it is expected. unfortunately I've got no experience with richfaces, so it's better to repost it in another question.

Comment: Used icefaces which is easy and atmosphere which required some cumbersome handling.

Comment: ok and can you give me an example which tag of icefaces does a hanging request, btw did you check with wireshark/charles etc if it really does an hanging request?

Comment: There is no tag for it in icefaces. http://facestutorials.icefaces.org/tutorial/easy-ajax-push.html I can see delayed requests under firebug, they show as 20 seconds long which  is duration I have chosen.